# Install KDE4 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kde4, kde5

Are there any packages to install KDE4 on Ubuntu 15.10?  I want to use Ubuntu 15.10 for the various bug fixes in lower-level libraries, but KDE5 itself is far too buggy to use.  (e.g. plasma crashes whenever an external monitor is plugged in/out)

Comment: The last KDE SC4 release `4.14.3` is available up to 14.04 release only. Unless you are willing to compile from source code, installing in newer releases looks impossible. More details on `4.14.3` can be read in [this KDE announcement](https://www.kde.org/announcements/announce-4.14.3.php).

Answer (score -1):

You could tried this, and type this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install kde-full
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.